# Is relying on Demorgan's law in open-source code a barrier to contribution?

Tags: programming-practices, open-source

I recently added this code to [a Github project I'm working on](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton/commit/07b5520ac6b8b56fc61ffa8ef527c53fa9c5204e):

```
    if not initial_push=='y' and not initial_push=='yes':
        print('Aborting.')
        return False
```

Since this is a public repository that I'm hoping people will contribute to, I am considering refactoring that bit as the slightly more readable code:

```
    if initial_push=='y' or initial_push=='yes':
        pass
    else:
        print('Aborting.')
        return False
```

If my goal is to keep the open-source project **accessible to outside contribution** then should I use the **more readable but clumsy** second method? I am actually interested in the answer for the **general case**, not just this specific example.

Comment: Both examples are equally readable to me, yet I prefer the first one since it's shorter. Also, if you return boolean value, shouldn't you return `True` instead of doing `pass`?

Comment: @scriptin it's probably used in a loop

Comment: @ratchetfreak maybe... who knows? =) I've seen people return results of mixed types a lot. If there is a loop, it should be included to make a better example.

Comment: Assuming this is Python, `if initial_push not in ('y', 'yes'):` is more readable than either.

Comment: What is the point of doing this? `github` has a good facility for pull requests...

Comment: This cannot possibly be the only time that a user is asked a question in the app. Therefore, per DRY, it should go into an appropriately named helper method, so your example code will be shorter and more readable still.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: This is in fact Python, and thanks for the tip!

Comment: @scriptin: The code is not used in a loop, but if the user aborts then the function should not continue. If the user does not abort, then there are additional things to do in the function.

Comment: @dotancohen then I even consider the second example invalid, since you're using `pass` just to invert a condition.

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question can be improved I would love to know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's invert the logic here, to keep in the spirit of Demorgan's law:

Would you want "programmers"  to contribute to your project even though they have problems with elementary logic? Is that a net benefit to you? Or will they be time wastes? Does your project have enough volunteers to review their code?

Comment: Good point! In fact, the application is intended to help ad-hoc system administrators, such as those who until recently were using Plesk. So I would like to keep the bar low. But your point definitely stands for other projects as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either of those two is really more complex or more difficult than he other. I'd choose the one without the unnecessary `pass` branch, because that's an unnecessary branch.

If you consider all the things that keep people from contributing to Open Source (it needs time, some programming ability, motivation, getting a Github account, making sense of the organization of a whole program, getting over the fear of not being good enough to contribute, actually creating a decent pull request, et cetera), I can't imagine that the choice of how to spell an if statement like this is ever going to make the difference between somebody contributing or not.

But in general, **readable and clumsy don't usually go together**. Almost always, the way that is more readable is also the less clumsy way, and the clumsy way takes more lines, more unnecessary cruft and is therefore less readable.

So: **always go for maximum readability.**